# Shell command with operator followed by pipes

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want a one line command to grab the most recent restart date from JBoss restart logs.  I'm currently using the following, which works

```
ls -rt $JBOSS_HOME/log/ser* | 
xargs grep -ih "Incomplete\s*Deploy" | 
awk '{print $1" "$2}' | tail -n 1
```

Now, I want to add an echo if the grep fails to match anything, i.e.:

```
ls -rt $JBOSS_HOME/log/ser* | 
xargs grep -ih "Incomplete\s*Deploy" || 
echo 'NO RESTART' | 
awk '{print $1" "$2}' | 
tail -n 1
```

The problem here is that it seems that the OR operator now causes anything following to go with the failed case.  How do I specify that I want to OR (echo) to be printed only when the grep fails?  When the grep succeeds it should work like the first command I posted.

Comment: `ls ... | xargs grep` is pointless (and a bad idea). grep can take multiple files at once.

Comment: For each file you are using `grep` on you want *either* the restart line or "NO RESTART"?

Comment: I am doing the ls -rt because there are multiple files. The logs rotate so it would be like server.log, server.log.1, ect.  All I want is the most recent one, which is why I'm sorting the logs before the grep, and then printing only the last match (regardless of which file).  If there are no matches anywhere, I would like to print 'NO RESTART'.

Comment: For that you can just stick the output in a variable and then use `"${var:-NO RESTART}"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `{` to group the terms:

```
ls -rt $JBOSS_HOME/log/ser* | 
xargs grep -ih "Incomplete\s*Deploy" && { 
    awk '{print $1" "$2}' | 
    tail -n 1 
} ||
echo 'NO RESTART'
```

or as one line:

```
ls -rt $JBOSS_HOME/log/ser* | xargs grep -ih "Incomplete\s*Deploy" && { awk '{print $1" "$2}' | tail -n 1; } || echo 'NO RESTART'
```

No additional subshell required.

Comment: Running the one line command isn't working for me, it's just printing a '>' on the next line as if the brackets aren't all closed.

Comment: Gotcha - Forgot the `;` awk and tail after - fixed! Try it now.

Comment: Awesome - that makes sense.  I like that this one doesn't require subshell either.  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can group commands within a pipe by using parentheses:

```
ls -rt $JBOSS_HOME/log/ser* | ( xargs grep -ih "Incomplete\s*Deploy" || echo 'NO RESTART' ) | awk '{print $1" "$2}' | tail -n 1
```

This makes the commands in the parentheses run in a subshell, which from the standpoint of the pipe, makes them work as a single command, i.e. they'll take the input and either print the `grep` match or `'NO RESTART'`, and then that will be fed into `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

```
res=$(ls -rt $JBOSS_HOME/log/ser* | xargs grep -ih "Incomplete\s*Deploy" | awk '{print $1" "$2}' | tail -n 1)

echo "${res:-NO RESTART}"
```

Also note that this is not safe for filenames with spaces/etc.